# Why doesn't Ractive capture every key pressed in an input on MacOS in InDesign?

Tags: javascript, ractivejs, adobe-indesign

I have an html input I have two-ways binded with Ractive:

```
<input type="password" value="{{password}}">
```

"password" here is a two-ways binded value in my Ractive. I then have a computed value using it:

```
computed : {
    validPassword : function() {
        return $.trim(this.get("password")).length > 0; 
    },
},
```

This computed value is used to (de)activate a button:

```
<div
    {{#if validPassword}}
    <button type="button" on-click="connect">connect</button>
    {{else}}
    <button type="button" disabled="disabled">connect</button>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

When I type something in the input, it seems the validPassword value is not recomputed by Ractive. But funnily, when I remove a character from the input, then the value is recomputed and the state of the button is updated.

Have I missed something in Ractive configuration that could make it recompute the computed value at each key pressed (any observer?)?

PS: This issue only happens on a Mac OS (10.9). This works fine on Windows.

Comment: On which browsers have you tried ? is that behaviour the same on Chrome/Safari ?

Comment: This is a bit special. I tested it in the embedded chromium engine v8 in Adobe InDesign and found this problem. In parallel, I have just tested it in firefox, chrome and safari, and this works fine. Maybe a bug in InDesign chromium engine?

Comment: It sounds like a bug in InDesign (possibly a very old Chromium). A possible workaround would be to listen for DOM events and update the value manually, rather than using two-way binding: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/4vo9y9vp/

Comment: @RichHarris This makes sense, and it works just fine. Just a question: where does the attribute `on-keydown-input-change` come from? I have neither seen it in HTML spec nor in Ractive one.

Comment: In Ractive you can create an `on-[event]` directive, which sets up event listening on the node. `on-keydown-input-change='...'` is just shorthand for `on-keydown='...' on-input='...' on-change='...'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must really be a bug in the embedded chromium of InDesign.

Anyway, as proposed by Rich Harris, the solution that works is the following workaround, in its proposed [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/4vo9y9vp/) with the essential line:

```
<input type="password" value="{{password}}" on-keydown-input-change='set("password",event.node.value)'>
```

InDesign engine on Mac OS seems not to understand the use of a `value`attribute in the `input` tag for the two-ways binding. You must use the `on-keydown-input-change` attribute and manually set the value in Ractive to bind the value from HTML to JS

EDIT: You can even use a simple on-keydown-input attribute (remove the change). This does the trick.